# Difference Between the Three OCR Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, ocr

Least Square Error Recognition from JavaOCR finds the least mean square error from a training image pixel by pixel.

Logistic regression from [this site](http://davinci.fmph.uniba.sk/~uhliarik4/recognition/files/thesis.pdf), on the other hand, seeks to minimize the error function.

I also found a neural network [here](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/files/acad_depts/csse/csse_technical_reports/csse10-05.pdf) that seems to do the same.

Are the algorithms for the three just the same? Please specify the specific differences if there are any. I've been searching over the net for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, neural networks are equivalent to non-linear logistic regression.  In fact, constructing models that minimize the error between predicted and actual labels is the high level goal of all of supervised learning.  This is one of the reasons why SVM's are so popular because this goal is made explicit in their theoretical formulation.

JavaOCR does not seem to construct a model, it seems to construct n templates, where n is the size of the alphabet.  It then assigns labels to inputs by selecting the label that minimizes the square error.